# RefineryCMS: routing error introduced by portfolio gallery plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, refinerycms

I'm using [RefineryCMS](http://www.refinerycms.com/) as a rails CMS, it was working like a charm until I         followed the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649909/how-to-add-a-lightbox-style-image-gallery-to-a-refinery-cms-website) question to get a simple image gallery functionality going. Now I'm getting the same error as shown on [this](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2595) issue. I didn't change any of my rails code to introduce a link_to tag with a nil reference, however (there is a link_to image_tag line in the guide but I've commented that out and nothing changed), so it's happening in the autogenerated code I believe. Here's the full error I get when I login to refinery on my site:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Refinery::Authentication::Devise::Admin::Users#index
Showing /home/mpvoss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu_item.html.erb where line #1 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"refinery/refinery/portfolio/admin/galleries", :locale=>:en}
Extracted source (around line #46):            
44 message << " missing required keys: #{missing_keys.sort.inspect}"     unless missing_keys.empty?
45
46 raise ActionController::UrlGenerationError, message
47 end
48
49 def clear

Trace of template inclusion: /home/mpvoss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu.html.erb, /home/mpvoss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/core/app/views/layouts/refinery/admin.html.erb
```

Note: Just loading the website without logging into refinery works because it's not trying to load the menu code below that encounters the routing issue.

Okay, let's have a look at **_menu.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to menu_item.title, refinery.url_for(menu_item.url),
        :class => ("active" if menu_item.highlighted?(params)),
        :id => "plugin_#{menu_item.name}" %>
```

This code just makes a menu bar for all the plugins. It can be commented out and refinery works (the error above goes away), but I need that menu bar to make changes to the website.

**What I've tried.**

- I found a galleries_controller.rb in ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-portfolio-289b85b18771/app/controllers/refinery/portfolio/admin, which seems to be the controller the error was talking about. It didn't have an index action, so I added an empty action to see if that was the problem and nothing changed. The routes.rb for the ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-portfolio-289b85b18771/ gem is below
- Commenting out the portfolio gem in my Gemfile and running bundle install but I get the same error because the autogenerated code (referring to stuff like .rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/) is still getting executed (I use git for version control and make a clean clone of the project before these changes and it has the same problem because the autogenerated code is not part of the version control).
- gem uninstall of the refinery-photo-gallery, refinerycms-page-images and refinerycms-portfolio gems I thought might be causing the problem
- I moved all the gems in ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/ out of that directory to see if a bundle install would regenerate fresh, clean gems but nothing changed.

None of these ideas has made a difference.  If any clarification is needed please just let me know. I've been stumped on this for a week and my Googling skills are failing me. Any help is really appreciated!

**~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-portfolio-289b85b18771/routes.rb**

```
 Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.draw do

  # Frontend routes
  namespace :portfolio, :path => Refinery::Portfolio.page_url do
    root :to => "galleries#index"
    resources :galleries, :only => [:index, :show]
  end

  # Admin routes
  namespace :portfolio, :path => '' do
    namespace :admin, :path => Refinery::Core.backend_route do
      scope :path => 'portfolio' do
        resources :galleries, :except => :show do
          get :children, :on => :member
          post :update_positions, :on => :collection
          resources :items, :except => [:show] do
            post :update_positions, :on => :collection
          end
        end
        resources :items do
          post :update_positions, :on => :collection
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:     https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger     console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the     background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

# Added by Matthew, Thin server
gem 'faye'
gem 'thin'

group :assets do
  #gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
  #gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass','~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  #gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'refinerycms', git: 'https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms', branch: 'master'
#gem 'refinerycms-page-images', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'quiet_assets', group: :development
#gem 'refinerycms-photo-gallery', '~> 0.1.0'
# Add support for searching inside Refinery's admin interface.
gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed', ['~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.0']

# Add support for Refinery's custom fork of the visual editor WYMeditor.
gem 'refinerycms-wymeditor', ['~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.6']
gem 'refinerycms-portfolio', github: 'refinery/refinerycms-portfolio', branch:     'master'
# The default authentication adapter
gem 'refinerycms-authentication-devise', '~> 1.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in the portfolio/images plugin, tried another bundle update and the updated code worked like a charm.  <3 RefineryCMS contributors